# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, determine eigenvalues of $A^2$ and $A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Also what is an eigenvalue of $A^n$?

I know you can square the eigenvalues, etc... but how do I prove this for a general case?

Comment: If $Av=\lambda v$, can you show $A^nv=\lambda^nv$?

Comment: For a square matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, you have $\lambda^n$ as an eigenvalue of $A^n$ where $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. If we know that $A$ is non-singular (i.e., $A$ is invertible), the result can be extended to negative integers, i.e., $\lambda^{-n}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^{-n}$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.
$$~$$
The proof of the first part is trivial using the definition $AX=\lambda X$ and pre-multiplying both sides with $A$ $(n-1)$ times. The proof of the second part is similar but you pre-multiply with $A^{-1}$ $n$ times.

Answer (score 2):

If $p(x)$ is a rational function defined on the spectrum of $A$ then the spectrum $$\sigma(p(A))=p(\sigma(A))$$

The spectrum being the set with all the eigenvalues or in a more precise way $\sigma(A)$={ $\lambda I-A$ is not invertible}.

Such definition is because this theorem comes from operator theory where in principle $A$ doesn't have to be a matrix, but in you case you can take the ordinary definition of spectrum being all the eigen values of $A$. So in your special case: $\sigma(A^m)=(\sigma(A))^m$ where the last is an abuse of notation to indicate $\sigma(A)$= {$\lambda^n$ : $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ }

If you'd like some demonstration, it does need a little bit of effort but essentially you can work it out starting from the "Jordan Canonical Form" noticing that the matrix $J$ which represent the canonical form of $A$ is the result of $J=D+N$ in other word is the result of a $D$ diagonal matrix and a $N$ nihilpotent matrix. Then you apply the function and you will work out more or less the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

If $E$ is an eigenspace of $A$ correspoinding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ then
$A$ acts as a multiplication by $\lambda$ operator on $E$, that is,
$A x = \lambda x$ if $x \in E$.

Note that $AE \subset E$, so you can apply $A$ again, where it still acts as a multiplication by $\lambda$ operator on $E$. Hence $A(A x) = A(\lambda x) = \lambda Ax = \lambda ^2 x$.